# Java Inheritance - finding total amount

Tags: java

I want to find the total amount of payment, but when I compile and run the code, I get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException.
```

payment class

```
package tutorial3;
    public class Payment {
        private double amount;
        public Payment()
        {
         this(0.0);
        }
        public Payment(double amount)
        {
         setAmount(amount);
        }
        public void setAmount(double amount)
        {
            this.amount = amount;
        }

        public double getAmount()
        {
            return amount;
        }

        public String toString()
        {
            return "amount paid is " + getAmount();
        }
    }
```

---

main class:

```
 public class main {
        public static void main(String[] args){   
            Payment [] p = new Payment[2];
            Scanner sales = new Scanner (System.in);
            double total = 0;
            for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
            {
             System.out.print("Sales amount? ");
             double amt = sales.nextInt();
             Payment cash = new Payment(amt);
            }        
            for( Payment pv : p  ){
                total += pv.getAmount();
            }
        }      
    }
```

Comment: you did initiliaze the array, but not the elements inside the array, hence you get a `NPE`.

Comment: Also, you never _set_ the amount of all those payments...

Comment: Oh, and you use a constructor on `Payment` that doesn't exist. You write `Payment cash = new Payment(amt);`, but there is no constructor in `Payment` that takes a `double` argument. This code doesn't compile.

Comment: I reposted the full code again, what's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to assign the created `Payment` instances to your array (and in addition the indices in your loop were wrong) :

```
        for(int i=0; i<pv.length; i++)
        {
          System.out.print("Sales amount? ");
          double amt = sales.nextDouble(); // it makes more sense to use nextDouble if
                                           // you are storing the result in a double
          pv[i] = new Payment(amt);
        }
```

BTW, I'm assuming your `Payment` class has a constructor that takes a `double`, or your code wouldn't pass compilation.

Answer (score 0):

You have created `Payment cash` but it was not assigned to one of the elements of `Payment` object array ( `Payment p[]` )

Replace

```
 Payment cash = new Payment(amt);
```

with

```
p[i] = new Payment(amt);
```

---

```
for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
     System.out.print("Sales amount? ");
     double amt = sales.nextDouble(); // change int to double
     p[i] = new Payment(amt);
 }
```